# How do I mount zap/wrk directory for ZAP API Scan on Windows

Tags: docker, zap, openapi.net

I am trying to run a ZAP API scan against an API but when I run the command below I get error  "***Invalid option v : option -v not recognized***" :

```
docker run  -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t http://100.100.333.888:0000/account?field4=4488082040118"&"field7=GENERIC01"&"field10=ABC076 -f openapi -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -r ZAP_Report.html
```

I want to generate the scan report and dump to the same directory. My understanding is that the command `-v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw` will map the /zap/wrk/ directory in the docker image to the current working directory (cwd) of the machine in which I am running docker.

Checked the wiki here : [ZAP APIScan WIKI](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/api-scan/) but it also appears as if the flag **-v** is not supported with APIScan.

When I run the same command I also get another error ***Could not find custom hooks file at /home/zap/.zap_hooks.py***.

My issues :

Is there ***another specific flag*** that is used with ZAP API scan to mount the /zap/wrk directory?

Why I do need to have a file .zap_hooks.py and if so ***where*** would I need to create it ?  I have found a sample here [Hook](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/scan-hooks/) (Is this the correct template)

Comment: You seem to have some misplaced quotes in the middle of your URL, surrounding ampersands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-v` flag is a docker option not a ZAP one, so your command should be `docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py ...`

If you dont think you need a hook file then you dont need to supply one. They are explained on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/scan-hooks/

Comment: After making that change I get error  : docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: What command are you using? There will be a problem with it but I cant tell just from that error message ;)